# DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type. in c# MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

i want to execute this query in EF 4.5:

```
db.UPTO_CarReceiption.Where(u => (DateTime.Now - u.RegisterDate).TotalMinutes <= 30).Select(i => i.TechnicalReviewCenterId)
```

But i get this error :

> DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this :

```
   ViewBag.OnlineATE = db.UPTO_CarReceiption.Where(u => EntityFunctions.DiffMinutes(u.RegisterDate,DateTime.Now)<30).Select(i => i.TechnicalReviewCenterId).Distinct().Count();
```